# Sublime Text - Как как удалить одинаковые символы в конце 1600 строк?

Tags: html, css, sublime-text

Sublime Text - Как как удалить одинаковые символы в конце 1600 строк?

Знаю, что можно как-то выделить все строки (ctrl+a) и массово переместить курсор на конец всех строк, тогда достаточно будет использовать клавишу "backspace" для удаления последних символов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел. Нужно выделить весь текст и зажать CRL+SHIFT+L, тогда курсор во всех строках перейдет в конец

Answer (score 0):

Выделить всё и написать регулярку, которая заменяет то, что нужно на пустое место. В меню `заменить на` можно использовать регулярки, если нажать специальную кнопку.